Do a transformer's embeddings self-organise the same way as word2vec embeddings?
Word2vec embeddings are well-known for being able to do vector arithmetic on them. So King - Queen ≈ Man - Woman. Or Germany - Berlin ≈ France - Paris.
When I first learned about transformers, one of the things that surprised me was they were randomly initialized, not taken from word2vec (or similar) embeddings. But, of course, it still works.
But I don't recall ever having seen any analysis of the embeddings at the end of transformer training. My assumption has always been they've stayed fairly random, and there is no (human-understandable) self-organisation going on. I.e. King - Queen ≈ Man - Woman. Or Germany - Berlin ≈ France - Paris would not work. Is this correct?
Note: if so is this a natural consequence of using SentencePiece (or equivalent)? So e.g. embedding #60 is "is", #117 is "man", but #118 is "par", and #119 is "wo".
Or can you average the embeddings for "wo" and "man" to get an embedding for "woman", and similarly for "is" and "par" to get "Paris", and then do useful vector arithmetic on those?
Background Aside: this came up in a discussion of using Maximum Mean Discrepancy to compare the embeddings for two sentences produced by a transformer model, and wondering if it is reasonable to say that a lower value equates to more similar sentences. Maybe this is still a valid assumption even if word2vec-style arithmetic is not possible?
